# Subgroup of a semidirect product is a semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product

Suppose $T$ and $U$ are subgroups of a group $G$, $G = T \ltimes U$ is a semidirect product, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $U$. Prove that $H = (H \cap T) \ltimes U$.

First, in this notation is $U$ meant to be the normal subgroup in the construction? In Dummit & Foote, the sign is flipped and the normal group is on the left. My understanding is that wherever the semidirect product sign crosses, the group on that side is the normal one. In that case, I would begin by noting that since $T \cap U = \{1\}$, and $U$ is normal in $G$, then $U$ is also normal in $H$, and $H \cap T \cap U$ is also trivial. But I have to check that my multiplication is properly defined too. This is where I really need to know for sure which of the groups is supposed to be normal.

Comment: The mnemonic I was taught is that the "triangle" points to the normal subgroup, just like in $N\triangleleft G$ or $G\triangleright N$.

Comment: @stewbasic Nice! I was thought that the vertical line is put on the side of the "defective" (not normal) subgroup, the one which prohibits the direct product. While the other side of the cross sign is normal as the subgroup is normal as in the direct product

Comment: That lines up with what I thought here too. So $H \cap T$ is acting on $U$ then, and we define multiplication as $(u_{1}, j_{1})(u_{2}, j_{2}) = (u_{1} j_{1} \cdot u_{2}, j_{1} j_{2})$. (This is how Dummit and Foote would write it.) I guess I'm just wondering what exactly there is to prove here.

Comment: @BMac This is an internal semidirect product, so you don't need to define multiplication. You just need to check one of the equivalent conditions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_semidirect_product_definitions (you already have $T\cap U=\{1\}$, so it would suffice to show $H=(H\cap T)U$)

Comment: Sorry to comment an old question, I was wondering if anyone know a reference where we can find this result. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not much you need to show, it suffices to show that we can write any $h \in H$ *uniquely* as:

$h = tu$ with $t \in H \cap T$ and $u \in U$.

But since $G = TU$ (because it is a(n internal) semi-direct product of $T$ and $U$), and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, we know there is such a $T,U$ decomposition of $G$; that is, we know we can write:

$h = tu$ uniquely for $t \in T$, and $u \in U$.

So if we can show *that* $t$ is also in $H$, we're done.

But $t = hu^{-1}$, and both $h,u \in H$.