# Is every subgroup of $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a semidirect product $T \rtimes Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry, isometry, semidirect-product

It is well known that the group of isometries of Euclidean space $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ splits as the semidirect product $\mathbb{R}^n \rtimes O(n)$. However, is it also true that every subgroup $G \le \mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product $T \rtimes Q$, where $T = G \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ (this is a slight abuse of notation) and $Q$ is the projection of $G$ onto $O(n)$?

My initial instinct is that this is false. Indeed, suppose that we have a subgroup $G$ satisfying the condition that: for every $\psi \in G$, $\psi(x) = Ax + b$, where $A \in O(n)$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if $A$ is not the identity, then $b \ne 0$. That is, in $G$ there are no isometries of the form $x \mapsto Ax$ where $A$ is not the identity. Suppose further that $G$ is not comprised solely of translations. Then $G$ cannot be isomorphic to the semidirect product, because $\{0\} \times Q \ne \{0\} \times \{I\}$ is a subgroup of $T \rtimes Q$. To be explicit, no map $\phi : T \rtimes Q \rightarrow G$ can be injective, since $G$ is in bijective correspondence with the proper subset $G' \subsetneq T \rtimes Q$ where $G' = \{(b,A) \in T \rtimes Q \, | \,\exists \psi \in G, \psi(x)=Ax+b\}$.

The only problem with this approach is that it assumes the existence of such a $G$, and thus far I have failed to produce an example. I would very much appreciate some help with this. Am I wrong; does the result in fact hold? Otherwise, is there a better way to prove its falsity? I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: In general, for subgroups of semidirect products, we have [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400751/subgroup-of-a-semidirect-product-is-a-semidirect-product). But this is only for the case that $H$ contains one factor.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but here $G$ does not necessarily contain all the translations $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Comment: No, certainly not.

Comment: I would expect that you can come up with counter examples by considering $n=2$ and one parameter subgroups $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\mathrm{Isom}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ that rotate (e.g. $p(\gamma(t))$ is the rotation of angle $t$) and translate ($\gamma(2\pi)$ is a non-identity translation). In this case the translations in the image, i.e. $T=G\cap\Bbb{R}^2$ where $G=\gamma(\Bbb{R})$, form a discrete group and the projection $Q$ of $G$ is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: I expect that given such a one parameter group $\gamma$ it induces a homeomorphism onto its image, in particular $G$ would be connected. Whatever semi-direct product structure you would consider involving $T$ and $Q$ it would produce group with infinitely many connected components and couldn't be isomorphic to the connected group $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper answer but a proposal for where to potentially find simple counter examples.

---

Consider a one parameter subgroup $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\mathrm{Isom}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ that

- actually rotates (e.g. $p(\gamma(t))$ is the rotation of angle $t$) and
- actually translates ($\gamma(2\pi)$ is a non-identity translation).

I expect under these circumstances $\gamma$ induces a homeomorphism onto its image. In any case, the image $G=\gamma(\Bbb{R})$ is connected.

The translations in the image, i.e. $T=G\cap\Bbb{R}^2$, form a *discrete group* and the projection $Q$ of $G$ is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Whatever semi-direct product structure you would consider involving $T$ and $Q$ it would produce group with infinitely many connected components and couldn't be isomorphic to the connected group $G$.

---

I imagine it should be easier to do in $\Bbb{R}^3$ taking something like $$\gamma(t)\big(V\big)=R_t V + te_z$$ where $R_t$ is the rotation of angle $t$ around the axis $Oe_z$.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts Olivier. Just to clarify, $p$ refers to the projection from $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ onto $O(n)$? I understand the idea behind your argument, however does it not only show that $G$ and $T \rtimes Q$ are not homeomorphic? Or is it the case that any potential group isomorphism induces a homeomorphism? Moreover, what are the topologies that we are considering on $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $T \rtimes Q$?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is the projection onto $O(n)$. It's more than just there being no homeomorphism: the semi-direct product will contains a copy of $SO(2)$ which has torsion; there therefore can't exist a group isomorphism with $G$ which will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$.

Concerning the topologies involved: you can see the isometry group of $\Bbb{R}^n$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}(\Bbb{R})$ and endow it with the subspace topology. As a set the semi-direct product is the cartesian product and you put the product topology on it.

Comment: I see. So, just to make sure I have the details correct in my head; if there exists an isomorphism between $G$ and the semidirect product, this induces an isomorphism between the copy of $SO(2)$ and a non-trivial subgroup of $G$, which in turn is isomorphic to a non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction since $SO(2)$ has torsion, whilst $\mathbb{R}$ is torsion-free. This being the case, we don't need to consider the topologies on the groups whatsoever, yes?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for your help Olivier. I'll accept your answer and try to produce a one parameter subgroup to finish the job. That being said, to anyone else reading this, I would still be very interested in seeing any other potential solutions to this problem!

Comment: No problem Matthew. The family $\gamma(t)$ of rigid motions in $\Bbb{R}^3$ I describe above should do: it is a one parameter subgroup and the only translations it contains are those by integer multiples of $2\pi e_z$. Also it projects down to a copy of SO(2) embedded in SO(3) as those rotations with axis Oz. You can probably find a 2D example but I'd be surprised if you can get any more transparent than this.